# Python subprocess grep command returns different answer every time

Tags: python, random, grep, subprocess

I'm trying to launch a grep on a file withing python with the code:

```
def runProcess(self, cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, bufsize=16000, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')
```

The problem is that i get different matches every time i launch it. Some lines are simply skipped in the return object. Much like the buffer had been overwritten. I have tried every way i found with subprocess to make this work but all lead to the same problem.

For information i have tested my grep command directly in a shell and it works perfectly, here is what i pass as the cmd argument to my function

```
['egrep', '-wi', '-nr', "'keyword1|keyword2|blabla'", 'test/match_inside.txt']
```

i've also tried using different values for bufsize (and no value ofc)

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), including some sample input file that provides different values when you run it. (And unless you know the platform, platform version, Python version, grep version, are irrelevant, provide that information as well.)

Comment: My issue is solved but for the sake of understanding i will do that sir !

Comment: using regexes: [`((i, line, m.group(1)) for i, line in enumerate(file, start=1) for m in re.finditer(r'(?i)\b(keyword1|keyword2|blabla)\b', line))`](http://ideone.com/3wQKBa)

Comment: I actually have trouble reproducing my issue with a SSCCE.
By having the simple quote in my args i match only 1 line in my file (where i should match 5) but the line i match never changes contrary to my real code where i usually miss 1 or 2 lines with them changing every time.
I'm kinda confused right now, and there is obviously another thing in my code that made this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue goes away (in my tests) when you instead invoke:

```
['egrep', '-wi', '-nr', 'keyword1|keyword2|blabla', 'test/match_inside.txt']
```

The [docs for Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) indicate that shlex.split() demonstrates how command line arguments should be made into a list of strings. In their example, outer quotations are removed from individual arguments.

EDIT: Our familiarity with bash may be misleading us. But Bash is just another scripting language. If you enter

```
grep 'a|b|c' target.txt
```

bash is invoking an operating system call (exec or some variant on Linux) to create a new grep process. Bash parses that command and removes the quotation marks; they are not a part of the option to grep, they are there to help bash scan your input by grouping tokens. Grep will be passed a string array of parameters (that's what argv is in C), so arguments don't need enclosing quotation marks; the structure and grouping of arguments is created by the string array.

When you use

```
"'keyword1|keyword2|blabla'"
```

in python, you are essentially passing

```
'keyword1|keyword2|blabla'
```

on to grep as complete string, when you really only want grep to have

```
keyword1|keyword2|blabla
```

as the string in index 3 (depending on # of preceding args) of argv.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why he gets different results each time he runs it. It would explain why he consistently gets no matches when he expects some matches (or gets fewer matches than he expected), but that's not what he claims the problem is.

Comment: Wow so simple... i feel kinda dumb, but i shall justify by saying that i had constructed my cmd first wanting to use it as a string and ended up transforming it into a list later because of the subprocess way of working.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Well after several tests it seems my issue is actually solved with this. So i'm gonna upvote. And you are right, i dont know why this actually works.

Comment: @user2171588 I have updated my response for a little more explanation. The confusion likely stems from our familiarity with bash.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but I cannot stop myself from asking:

Why running `grep` from within Python? And with subprocess?? If you **are** using Python then I strongly recommend reading [Python RE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It is much more powerful than grep, all in all (in my opinion) easier to understand and control.

edit: the question is pragmatic. I want to know why.

Comment: Well tbh, i came up with the grep solution because i was using pyparsing before to parse a VERY big chunk of data, and the performance is crucial. Pyparsing was so slow that i decided to split up the work and make a pre-analysis with grep thus keeping track of files/lines that match.
Now i'm gonna check Python RE, thanks for your comment

Comment: Takes some getting used to, just read hard about groups. And read again. All things parenthesis (?:...) (?!...) (?<!...) and so on. You can do multithreading or multiprocessing on RE as logn as you send different files to it and do not share the same instance of RE. It's efficient enough. Good luck!